# match a sentence with a sentence in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply, grepl

I have two data frame occupation and data. I want to match each occupation in data to occupation and assign coressponding class by adding a column in occupation dataframe.

```
occupation <- c("I am Civil Engineer human being", "Graphic Designer too late", "Architect by profession", "Sales Manager Bank", "Love my profession of Professor", "NA")

occupation <- data.frame(occupation)

data <- data.frame(class = c("Engineers","Designer","Artist","Designer","Poetry""Banker and Prof"), Occupation = c("Civil Engineer", "Graphic Designer", "Painter","Poetry","Architect(prof)", "Sales Manager Bank"))
```

I want output like this

```
 occupation                             class
    I am Civil Engineer human being        Engineers
    Painter  Architect Poetry              Artists
    Graphic Designer too late              Designers
    Architect by Painter profession        Architect
    Sales Manager Bank                     Banker and Prof
    Love my profession of Professor        NA
      NA                                   NA
```

I tried but its responding anything

```
occupation$value <- sapply(data$occupation, grepl, x = occupation)
```

Comment: Try searching for "r fuzzy match" till you find something you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how complex your data is, but this is useful for low complex strings. Use `agrep` function allow you to set a tolerance parameter so you can match no-equal strings:

```
occupation <- data.frame(occupation = c("I am Civil Engineer human being", "Graphic Designer too late", "Architect by profession", "Sales Manager Bank"), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data <- data.frame(class = c("Engineers","Designer","Architect","Banker and Prof"), 
                   occupation = c("Civil Engineer", "Graphic Designer", "Architect(prof)", "Sales Manager Bank"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

occupation$value <- sapply(occupation$occupation, function(x) {
    match.class <- sapply(data$class, function(y) agrep(y, x, max.distance = 0.2))
    data$class[which(match.class == 1)]
  }
)
```

If you rise `max.distance` you can detect the last text but previos strings will do it too.

```
                       occupation            value
1 I am Civil Engineer human being   Civil Engineer
2       Graphic Designer too late Graphic Designer
3         Architect by profession  Architect(prof)
4              Sales Manager Bank
```

A second option match every word, but for the case 'I am Civil Engineer human being' the words 'I' and 'am' match everything.

```
occupation$value <- sapply(occupation$occupation, function(x) {
    match.class <- sapply(data$class, function(y) {
      any(sapply(strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]], function(z)
        any(agrep(z, y, max.distance = 0.2))))
    })
    data$class[which(match.class)]
  }
)
```

So this is the result ...

```
                       occupation                                                                 value
1 I am Civil Engineer human being Civil Engineer, Graphic Designer, Architect(prof), Sales Manager Bank
2       Graphic Designer too late                                                      Graphic Designer
3         Architect by profession                                                       Architect(prof)
4              Sales Manager Bank                                                    Sales Manager Bank
```

[Here thelink when you can download the code](https://drive.google.com/a/humboldt.org.co/file/d/0B3J9l9VrPJBRM3NYNUJNVEV4a2s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am not asking this which you have answered. I think some misunderstanding. I want to find out the class not Occupation from the occupation dataframe.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I changed `data$occupation[which(match.class)]` by `data$class[which(match.class)]`in the code at the 10th line of first code and 6th line of second code

Comment: Thanks. If there are more than one occupation in occupation field like I edited above and i want class of first occupation only.what will be the code for that??/

Comment: Just replace `data$class[which(match.class)]` by `data$class[which(match.class)[1]]` in the same lines mentioned above

Comment: The above code is not working I mean option 1 giving output integer(0) and second option is giving error strsplit(x, " ") : non-character argument.

Comment: I just edited the post adding the link when you can download the code, I just copy-paste the script in the code and works!

Comment: Yes, it's working for this dataset, this the sample dataset of my dataset around 3000rows. And I am applying this code on a dataset of 3000, and it's not working for that. it's showing non-character argument. What the problem I don't know, still trying to find out.

Comment: Maybe try using `str()` function to check the class of your columns and see what its diferent from working dataset

Comment: Can you try with ypur first 5 values? [1:5] Maybe we can detect if error is about data class or some strange text

Comment: I tried str() function. Accordingly, i convert data frame of factors to character. Now the  Error during wrapup: 'pattern' must be a non-empty character string.

Comment: And for first 5 data, the 2 and  3 occupations matched with every class and remaining data resulting in NA that ok.Because no matchable occupation present.

Comment: Can you send me the first 20 values? gonzalezgarzon.ivan@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

`agrep` comes pretty close. I was unable to get it to work for `Architect(prof)` but if you remove the parentheses, it works:

```
data$Occupation <- sub("\\(.*", "", data$Occupation)
data
            class         Occupation
1       Engineers     Civil Engineer
2        Designer   Graphic Designer
3        Designer          Architect
4 Banker and Prof Sales Manager Bank

occ.class <- data$class[unlist(sapply(data$Occupation, function(x) agrep(x, occupation)))]
occ.class
[1] Engineers       Designer        Designer        Banker and Prof
Levels: Banker and Prof Designer Engineers
```

If you want the 3rd one to show `Architect` you should change it accordingly in your `data` data.frame.

As for the edit:

```
occ.class <- unlist(sapply(data$Occupation, function(x) agrep(x, occupation)))
ifelse(length(occ.class), data$class[occ.class], NA)
```

Comment: I am getting the output like this.                                                         
 > occ.class
[1] "Engineers" "Engineers" "Engineers" "Engineers"

Comment: In the case of no case match.                                                                                      for example- I edited my question. Please go through it.

Comment: > occ.class
output: Civil Engineer   Graphic Designer   Architect  Sales Manager Bank 
                 1                  2                  3                  4                                             >ifelse(length(occ.class), data$class[occ.class], NA)
[1] 3                                                                                                                                        I am getting output like this. there is something wrong ?

Comment: If there are two occupations or more in a sentence, then the class is assigned to the first one only. What would be probably coding for that?                   for this go through the edited question. Thankful for your help.